# How to set graphics for a push button using Qt Designer?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I created a pushButton with a border image using Qt Designer. The stylesheet of the pushButton looks like the following.

```
border-image: transparent;
border-image: url(:/button_img/main_button.png);
```

The button looks like as follows:

[image]

The button works as expected but I do not know how can I set border inset or onset for that button. My terminologies might be wrong because I am very new to GUI development. What I am looking for is when you creata a normal pushButton, you can visualy see when you click that button. But in my case the button works but I cannot see the graphics when I click the button.

How can I add the border inset or onset? Please let me know in case of additional information.

Comment: What do you want the final result to look like? By setting the style sheet border image, you are effectively overriding all the other default styling for that button (including hover/pushed/checked states). If you just want to modify the central image, then it is much simpler to just set the `icon` property. OTOH if you do want to completely re-style the button, you'll need a more holistic approach, either how _musicmante_ describes or just setting different CSS properties for the various button states as described in https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qpushbutton

Comment: @MaximPaperno  I want to have a pushButton with a custom image. The image does not fit the complete area of pushButton so I want those area to be transparent with the background. And I still need the styling like hover/pushed/checked states.

Comment: Well, still not sure what "a pushButton with a custom image" means exactly. Is there text in this button? An icon? Is it some fixed size?  No idea.  However, you could try using a background image instead. Replace the CSS with: `background: url(:/button_img/main_button.png) no-repeat center;`

Comment: I meant a pushButton with a background image. Sorry for the confusion. I tried your suggestion and the button looks like [this](https://imgur.com/a/SrBN3Dg). But I want the white area inside the button around the play icon to be tranparent and still have the stylings like hover/pushed/checked states.

Comment: The background will be transparent if your PNG image has transparency... does it? It's hard to tell from the screenshot if that's the default button background showing through or the png image itself. Why don't you post main_button.png at least? Getting just little clues at a time is frustrating. And still not clear why you don't just use the image as an icon to begin with.

Comment: Image as an icon produces the same results. Here is the [main_button.png](https://imgur.com/a/2xqO59n), which has tranparency. I am sorry cause I have a very little or no knowledge in GUI dev.

Comment: I don't know what you expect/want it to look like. With the `background` CSS it looks as I would expect it to. You should provide a sketch of what you want (and is this the same button you now want rounded?). Also to be clear, to see any animations (hover/push/etc) you have to either Preview your design (in Designer/Creator, ALT-SHIFT-R), or run the app. In the static design mode you will not see any effects.

Comment: Yeah, I am aware that I have to preview the window to see the animations. I am expecting to have a pushButton with a background image. The image I want to use is [this](https://imgur.com/a/2xqO59n). So, once I add the background image to my pushButton it looks like [this](https://imgur.com/a/08M1YJ7). But I want the pushButton to look like [this](https://imgur.com/a/dc3cDD7). So, how to achieve this? Should the pushButton to be reshaped in a circle similar to the background image? Overall, I want a pushButton which looks exactly like my background image with all those animations.

Comment: Much clearer, thanks. Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22469885/how-to-create-a-circular-button-in-qt-designer) help? That should do what you want, just replace the `background` CSS properties with your image url (like I showed above). **But** you'll need two more images, for the hover and the pressed states. Also adjust the pixel sizes to match your image. Try it first w/out your image, just like in that answer, to get an idea of how it should work.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't; not like that.

As the name hints, the `border-image` CSS property is used to draw borders; while what you see seems like a "background image", it actually is a border object that splits your image in a 3x3 grid rectangle that covers the whole button area; each section is then "stretched" to fill its own rectangle.

```
+-----------+---------+------------+
| top left  |   top   | top right  |
+-----------+---------+------------+
|   left    |  center |   right    |
+-----------+---------+------------+
|bottom left|  bottom |bottom right|
+-----------+---------+------------+
```

To understand how all of this works, read the "Common Mistakes" section of the [stylesheet examples documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#qpushbutton-and-images). Here's what actually happens (I'm using half-width/half-height margins for the sake of the argument, so only the 4 "angle" rectangles are shown, so the `left`, `top`, `right`, `bottom` and `center` rectangles will be null):

[image: border-image issue screenshot]

If you want to use style sheets that interactively show borders, the standard approach is have 2 different images for the button state, and both of them needs their border. If you also want to achieve the "hover" effect, you'll need a third image that will have no border at all.

The downside of this method is that if the icon is resized, the border will be resized too.

The only alternative I can think of is to subclass your own QPushButton widget and override its paintEvent method. You could also use an [event filter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#eventFilter), but that wouldn't give you any major benefit, as it would use a very similar approach anyway, while complicating things if the object tree is even slightly complex.

In the following example I use an implementation that is based on stylesheets only: Qt can use the `qproperty-*` stylesheet parameter to set *existing* properties of a class (Qt properties that are already part of the class, or that are added in the class constructor: using `setProperty` on an unexisting property within the `__init__` method will *not* work).
While this kind of implementation is usually not required (you could set the pixmap attribute of the class instance by hand) the advantage is that with this approach you can set everything within the stylesheet only.

```
class PixmapButton(QtWidgets.QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap()
        self.setCheckable(True)
        self.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)

    @QtCore.pyqtProperty(QtGui.QPixmap)
    def pixmap(self):
        return self._pixmap

    @pixmap.setter
    def pixmap(self, pixmapPath):
        self._pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(pixmapPath)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        opt = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionButton()
        self.initStyleOption(opt)
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        # draw the basic button
        self.style().drawControl(QtWidgets.QStyle.CE_PushButton, opt, qp, self)
        if self._pixmap.isNull():
            return

        # get the minimum possible size for the pixmap icon
        minSize = min(self.width(), self.height())
        # remove the margin/padding usually necessary for the button contents
        minSize -= self.style().pixelMetric(QtWidgets.QStyle.PM_ButtonMargin, opt, self) * 2

        # create a rectangle based on the minimal size and move it to the center
        # of the button
        rect = QtCore.QRect(0, 0, minSize, minSize)
        rect.moveCenter(self.rect().center())

        # finally, draw the "icon"
        qp.drawPixmap(rect, self._pixmap.scaled(rect.size(), QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio, QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation))
```

Here's a test window that will show the `border-image` implementation on top (along with its border splitting), and the subclass painting at the bottom.

```
class Test(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)

        layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel('basic border-image'), 0, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        borderButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        layout.addWidget(borderButton, 1, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        borderButton.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        borderButton.setFixedSize(120, 120)
        borderButton.setStyleSheet('''
            border-image: url(play.png);
        ''')

        layout.addItem(QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(120, 0, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding))
        layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel('expanded border-image'), 0, 1, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        borderButtonExpanded = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        layout.addWidget(borderButtonExpanded, 1, 1)
        borderButtonExpanded.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        borderButtonExpanded.setStyleSheet('''
            border-image: url(play.png) 60 60 60 60;
            border-top: 60px transparent;
            border-bottom: 60px transparent;
            border-right: 60px transparent;
            border-left: 60px transparent;
        ''')

        layout.addItem(QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(0, 10))
        layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel('paintEvent implementation'), 2, 0, 1, 2, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        pmButton = PixmapButton()
        layout.addWidget(pmButton, 3, 0, 1, 2)
        pmButton.setMinimumSize(120, 120)
        pmButton.setStyleSheet('''
            QPushButton {
                qproperty-pixmap: url(play.png);
                /* hover mode: while there's no border shown, we can set the 
                default radius for the hover and pressed statuses */
                border: none;
                border-radius: 4px;
            }
            /* show border only if hovered or is checkable */
            QPushButton:hover, QPushButton[checkable="true"] {
                border: 1px outset green;
            }
            QPushButton:pressed, QPushButton:checked {
                border: 1px inset green;
            }
        ''')

        pmButton2 = PixmapButton()
        layout.addWidget(pmButton2, 4, 0, 1, 2)
        pmButton2.setCheckable(True)
        pmButton2.setMinimumSize(120, 120)
        pmButton2.setStyleSheet(pmButton.styleSheet())
```

Note: This is a very simplified implementation. It does *not* check if the user sets a custom icon for the button, and there should be no button text at all.